# Qualcomm Gimbal Network Error ios app

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am getting an ntewtork error from their server on application launch reading

`2014-03-27 16:46:05.356 C21[4222:60b] Failed to initialize gimbal Error Domain=QLRestTemplateErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x1700f3480 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, QL_HTTP_STATUS_CODE=400, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ios.api.gimbal.com/service/rest/v4/user/28414345/application, NSLocalizedFailureReason={"statusCode":10000,"errorMessage":"Application verification failed. Invalid com.iBeek.C21 for application with package com.iBeek.C21"}}
2014-03-27 16:46:05:359 C21[4222:60b] Error Occoured:Expected status code in (200-299), got 400
2014-03-27 16:46:05:501 C21[4222:60b] Error Occoured:Expected status code in (200-299), got 400
2014-03-27 16:46:06.018 C21[4222:9403] QLDDLogFileInfo: creationDate(log-03272014-164606.txt): getattrlist result = -1`

It looks like the verification failed but checked all the API keys and they were right. Not sure whats causing this.

Comment: Has your code ever worked or is this the first time you have tried? It looks like a problem on their back-end.   The package that is registered for the URL you requested is invalid in some way, but if this is new code I guess it is possible that you have something wrong.